# Javascript convert set to plain Array

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

[Set - Javascript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Example: Iterating Sets

line 16

`var myArr = [v for (v of mySet)];`

my code:

`var s_priceCatsArr = [ n for ( n of s_priceCats ) ];`

This produces the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for` on `Google Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m`

`Customise and control Google Chrome > Settings > About` tells me that my Google Chrome is up to date.

Am I doing something wrong or is this feature not supported?

***UPDATE:***

I went to `chrome://flags` and ticked `Enable Experimental JavaScript`. Then restarted my browser, but I still get the same error. I guess I'll just have to wait until that feature is added properly then... :(

Comment: As is **clearly** stated at the top of the documentation you linked, that's an ES6 feature. Chrome generally doesn't support those as soon as Firefox does.

Comment: @Pointy: But Kangax's table says Chrome 38 *does* support sets: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Set No idea about that specific syntax, the note on that says it doesn't have support for the constructors yet.

Comment: You can try looking at `chrome://flags` and select the "Enable experimental JavaScript" flag.  That's also mentioned in the page you linked!

Comment: Chrome doesn't support array comprehensions yet.  It does support (via that flag) the `Set` and `Map` APIs.  I was testing this just a day or two ago.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well I guess Set support and comprehension support are two different things?

Comment: @Pointy: Indeed. I couldn't tell whether that `[1]` referred just to OP25 or to CH38 *and* OP 25... :-) Re comprehensions, yeah, that's what I meant about syntax above.

Comment: @Alnitak: [No active development](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4990451081805824) :(

Comment: @georg the final comment suggests that as a language feature it has been pushed back to ES7.   The `Array.from` version is more powerful anyway, if a little more verbose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a Set to an Array in Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638234/how-to-convert-a-set-to-an-array-in-chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome does not yet (as of version 38.0.2125.111) support "Array comprehensions", i.e. `[expr of Iterable]`

The standard ES6 function to convert an *`Iterable`* into an `Array` is [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), but that's not in Chrome yet either.   For reasons I haven't yet discerned I can't get the MDN shim to work on a `Set`. (ah, according to the docs the shim doesn't support "true iterables")

Another approach that works in Firefox but (but again, not in Chrome) is the "spread" operator `...`:

```
> var s = new Set([1,2,3,4])
undefined
> [...s]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**EDIT** in Chrome 46 (and possibly earlier) all of `for (x of <Iterable>)`, `Array.from` and the `...` spread operator now work.