# How to convert a Set to an Array in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

[How to convert Set to Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069828/how-to-convert-set-to-array) gives three answers for converting a Set to an Array, none of which currently work in the Chrome browser.

Let's say I have a simple Set

```
var set_var = new Set(['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

I can iterate through my variable and add the elements to an empty array

```
var array_var = [];
set_var.forEach(function(element){array_var.push(element)});
```

But are there any other ways to do this that have wider browser support?

Comment: `Set` itself is part of ES6 Harmony. You won't find "wider browser support," given this is experimental technology for the time being. There are ways to iterate without `Array.prototype.forEach`, but those ways would be for browsers that don't support `Set` to begin with.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Okay, I hear you. Let's focus on Chrome then. Chrome does support `Set` just not all the functionality that other browsers support. Are there other ways to convert the Set to an Array in Chrome?

Comment: What about this, its more complicated but if you only want another way:

var mySet = Set(['a','b','c']);
iter = mySet.keys();
for(var i = 0; i < mySet.size; i++){
 console.log(iter.next().value[0])
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Set to Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069828/how-to-convert-set-to-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not give a try with set iterator?

```
function setToArray(set) {
  var it = set.values(),
      ar = [],
      ele = it.next();

  while(!ele.done) {
    ar.push(ele.value);
    ele = it.next();
  }

  return ar;
}

setToArray(new Set(['a', 'b', false, 0, 'c'])); // ["a", "b", false, 0, "c"]
```

Comment: Are there any advantages with a set iterator?

Comment: @Cecilia I'm not sure what you are looking for, performance, compatibility, or anything else. It's just one of many approaches. Honestly, I don't see significant difference from yours.

Comment: This implementation will fail if Set contains Falsy value. Always check current.finished instead of current.value

Comment: @garkin Missed that point given PO's sample data, updated answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend

`const array_var = [ ...set_var ]`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.